# Allow front-end editing of user forms?

Tags: joomla-3.x, rsform

Good day,

I was wondering if there is a component available which will allow me to do the following:

A user completes a form, submits it and receives an email upon submission. If they want to edit the form, they will be allowed to log in and go to a "directory" or "history" of their submissions and edit any submission they wish to.

Now, I am using RSForm Pro and it can do these things I ask of. The only issue is, the layout of the "Edit" page looks very bad. As in, just row below row. I want to present it in a more visually appealing way for the user, so they can edit the form easily if they want to.

Also, how do you go about sending an email notification once a change has been made? If the user decides to add one field in their form, they should receive an email with all the listed changes and such.

I looked at Breezingforms. I will do more research there and see if it can be done in a better way.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to do it, but most likely the edit/submissions layout of RSForm pro would be improvable. It should support template overrides and also you should be able to apply CSS changes to fine-tune it's look.

Regarding sending emails when there is a change in the form I guess you need to ask RSJoomla. Logically there should be a way using some php.

Apart of RSForm, as @Michael said in his answer, Fabrik is a great alternative and offers all you have described and even more. Again you can tweak it's layout the way you want. However, Fabrik has some learning curve in order to master it.

---

If you do a search in Joomla Extensions Directory you will discover a lot more similar Form/Application builder extensions: Chronoforms, BreezingForms, Cobalt, Seblod, FlexiContent and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Fabrik is pretty awesome for things like that.  You can totally customize the look of any form created in Fabrik.

Comment: I've tried to use Fabrik but it's quite difficult to learn.

Comment: There is quite a learning curve.